# Uploading images to IIS server failing

Tags: asp.net, image, iis, file-upload, upload

Below is my controller code to upload an image to my IIS server, locally this is  working fine but when live on my production IIS server the exception upload failed is returned each time. Does anyone have a solution?

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.Mvc;  

namespace website.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class UploadController : Controller
{

// GET: Upload  
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpGet]

public ActionResult UploadFile()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), _FileName);
            file.SaveAs(_path);
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
        return View();
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
        return View();
    }
}
}  
}
```

Comment: Evar what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi, i'm not certain how to access the detailed error message, i'm just receiving the viewbag.message 'file upload failed' in my view. I believe the error may be due to my IIS servers settings but am unsure what I need to change

Comment: You can't see the detailed error message because you're swallowing it. You need to catch the exception `catch (Exception exception)`, and then grab the details from the caught exception `exception.Message` or `exception.ToString()`. Preferably log them somewhere.